# How do I configure a static asset folder and set up pre-fetch in Vue CLI 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am using Cesium.js with Vue. Currently, I am linking the Cesium Unpkg repository, but that takes a long time to load. What I would really like to do is to configure the app to:

1) refer to a /static folder where I can link to the Cesium files directly

2) pre-fetch this folder's contents immediately on app load once all the immediately necessary stuff has loaded.

How can I do this via the vue-config.js file?

The existing file's contents are below.

```
module.exports = {

    publicPath: '/',

    outputDir: 'dist-new',

    lintOnSave: false,

    runtimeCompiler: true,

    transpileDependencies: [ ],

    productionSourceMap: true,

    chainWebpack: config => {
    },

    configureWebpack: config => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            config.optimization.splitChunks = false;
            config.optimization.minimizer[0].options.extractComments = true;
        }
    },

    css: {

        extract: {filename: 'styles.css'},

        modules: false,

        sourceMap: false,

        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                css: 'css-loader',
                'scss': 'css-loader | sass-loader'
            }
        }
    },

    parallel: require('os').cpus().length > 1,

    devServer: {
        open: process.platform === 'darwin',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8082,
        https: true,
        hotOnly: false,
        disableHostCheck: true,
        before: app => {
            process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TRANSPILE_MODULES = true;
        }
    },

    pluginOptions: {}

};
```

Comment: Curious as to why you want to provide it as a static asset rather than installing it via npm?

Comment: I don't really know how to make that work. I'm using Vue-Cesium as a wrapper, and the package's author suggested doing it that way. Inside the Vue-Cesium config, there is a way to link to the Unpkg link or an internal static asset.